# in javascripts When the Mr. or Mrs. radio button is clicked, it should be displayed in the P element, which is not the case

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

```
let input=document.querySelectorAll('input');
let button=document.querySelector('button');
let p=document.querySelector('p');

button.addEventListener('click',()=>{
p.innerHTML=`شما ${input.value}هستید`

})
```

When the Mr. or Mrs. radio button is clicked, it should be displayed in the P element, which is not the case

Comment: You're using `quesySelectorAll()`, so `input` is a ***collection*** of elements, not a single one. Therefore that variable has no `value` property for you to read

Comment: It would help to include your html.